# Want to make my checkbox disabled (grayed out) on a click of particular button using jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Want to make my checkbox disabled (grayed out) on a click of particular button using jquery :

My Code is below:

```
<div id="nameTesting">
<div class="checkbox">
    <label>
        <input checked="checked" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Value field is required." id="Name_Value" name="Name.Value" type="checkbox" value="true">
        <input name="Name.Value" type="hidden" value="false">
        Show My name
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: `disabled` should do it for you

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('#disableCheckbox').click(function() {
  $('#Name_Value').prop('disabled', true);
  $('.checkbox').css({
    color: '#bbb'
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="nameTesting">
<div class="checkbox">
    <label>
        <input checked="checked" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Value field is required." id="Name_Value" name="Name.Value" type="checkbox" value="true">
        <input name="Name.Value" type="hidden" value="false">
        Show My name
    </label>
</div>

<button id='disableCheckbox'>Disable</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy this code in your button click event/function

```
$("#Name_Value")[0].disabled=true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#Name_Value").prop('disabled', true);
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should also explain what the code does and how it helps. Also please mention any library that you might be using.

Comment: @yukashimahuksay Thanks for your suggestion, but since the jQuery is already mentioned in the question, I don't think there's any need to write in the answer,

it's but obvious that the answer would be in jQuery.